# required_if Laravel 5 validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I have form that a user can fill-out for selling their home. And for one of the in puts, a user must select weather it will be "For Sale" or "For Rent". If it is For Sale, two price input fields will appear, and if it is For Rent, then some other price input field will appear based off of jQuery.

My problem is I want the price fields to be required, BUT for example if I'am selecting "For Rent", and then I submit my form, it will give me an error saying the price fields for the "For Sale" input fields are required, even though it is under the "For Rent" section.

I know there is a *required_if* in Laravel, but I just dont know how to utilize that. Here is my Requests for a Property.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class PropertyRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'list_type' => 'required',
            'sale_price' => 'required', // <-- maybe like: required_if:value
            'rent_price' => 'required',   
        ];
    }
}
```

/****************** EDIT ***************************/

What I have now:

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'list_type'  => 'required',
            'sale_price' => 'required_if:list_type:For Sale',
            'rent_price' => 'required_if:list_type:For Rent',
    }
```

But I get this error when I submit the Form:

[image: My Error]

Comment: Good place to look is the tests (v5.6): https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/681438e78a1ccc5462cfa20e0e724befbb9269a1/tests/Validation/ValidationValidatorTest.php#L880

Answer (score 158, accepted):

assuming that list_type is the name of the select box to choose from (values : selling or rent)

use it this way

```
"sale_price" => "required_if:list_type,==,selling"
```

**what does this mean?**
:

the sale price is only required if the value of list_type is equal to `selling`

do the same for `rent_price`

**edit**

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
   'list_type'  => 'required',
   'sale_price' => 'required_if:list_type,==,For Sale',
   'rent_price' => 'required_if:list_type,==,For Rent'
}
```

Comment: check my edit, made a mistake try now, if this didnt work, add , ==, like this `sale_price" => "required_if:list_type,==,selling"`

Comment: Your **edit** section of your comment worked. Thank You.

Comment: The code from above is not relevant, because with `list_type` => `required` there is no sense to write next 2 validation rules, because they ALWAYS will be required, as `list_type` is also `required` instead of `sometimes`.

Comment: @lura Varzari i don't really get what you mean, the next 2 validation rules depends on the value of the first `list_type` :) if `list_type == "for sale"` there must be a `sale_price` field else if it's rent there must be a `rent_price` field

Comment: You saved my time @AchrafKhouadja , Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

You could use the `Illuminate\Validation\Rules\RequiredIf` rule directly.

Note: This rule is available in Laravel 5.6 and up.

```php
class SomeRequest extends FormRequest
{
    ...
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'sale_price' => new RequiredIf($this->list_type == 'For Sale'),
            'rent_price' => new RequiredIf($this->list_type == 'For Rent'),
        ];
    }
}
```

And if you need to use multiple rules, then you can pass in an array.

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'sale_price' => [
            new RequiredIf($this->list_type == 'For Sale'),
            'string',
            ...
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: Use this when you have your validation logic in a class extending from `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest`.

Comment: Just for context, This didn't exist at the time of the question, it was introduced in later laravel version

Answer (score 13):

There can be another situation when, the requirement will be required if another field is not present, if someone is in this situation, you can do

```
'your_field.*' => 'required_unless:dependency_field.*,
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use **`Illuminate\Validation\Rule`** in Laravel as given below to build the validator.

```php
$validator =  Validator::make( $request->input(), [
    'list_type' => 'required',
    'sale_price'=> Rule::requiredIf( function () use ($request){
        return $request->input('list_type') == 'For Sale';
    }),
    'rent_price'=> Rule::requiredIf( function () use ($request){
        return $request->input('list_type') == 'For Rent';
    }),
]);
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, with this ***required_if*** i needed to check with two values and I wrote as

```
return [
        'change_status' => 'required',
        'forward_to' => 'required_if:change_status,2,3'
    ];
```