# Laravel 5.5 / Validator / Custom rules

Tags: laravel, validation

(edited to clearer purpose)

I discovered Laravel some months ago and I followed some Laracast videos. Now, I'm stuck with a problem of custom Validator.

I've got normal and permanent rules (date | required | min / max) to verify my form request. This part works.

But I've got a custom validation which could be verified as a normal rule IF one of the request parameter - select1 - is set to 1 (for exemple).

I read a dozen of explanation but nothing clear enough.

So, let start with my code. Thank you for your indulgence...
My question is into the customTest function on the bottom.

Thank you,

1/ I made a new Request with

```
php artisan make:controller priceRequest.php
```

2/  I made some rules and changed some lines.

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

// Permanent RULES
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'field1' => 'required|min:1|max:15',
        'field2' => 'required',
        'date1' => 'required|date',
        'select1' => 'required',
    ];

    return $rules;
}
```

Then I integrated a new function to perform a custom verification

```
public function withValidator($validator) {
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        if (!$this->customTests($this->request->get('data'))){
            $validator->errors()->add('custom', 'Something is wrong');
        }
    });
}
```

Finally, I wrote the customTests function and it is inside this one I'm stuck !!

```
public function customTests($data) {

    if ($data['select1'] == 1) {

        // HERE MY QUESTION
        // I'd like to verify that $data['date2']
        // is a date and is set. So, I'd like to
        // add a rule to rules (has I made with
        // 'date1' => 'required|date',
        // and return TRUE if the rule match or
        // FALSE

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Sorry, the questions are right in the code :-(

Comment: Try to define it in other way. No one knows what you need.

Comment: Hello Adam, I thought I was clear enough.
On the question B, I'd like to add a 'normal' rule like in the rule function instead of writing tests to check date.
I don't know how to add this rule to the validator. I checked with :

$v = Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'games' => 'required|numeric',
]);

But I don't know what to pass int the $data variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [required\_if Laravel 5 validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777265/required-if-laravel-5-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the solution to my problem.

I made a mistake and a confusion because I tried to add the new rule into the ->after() function.

So, the correct code is the following :

```
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->sometimes('ticket.price', 'required|integer|min:0.1', function ($input) {
    if ($any_condition_who_need_to_verify_new_rule) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        # Everything is perfect, this rule cas be omitted
    }

    $validator->after(function ($validator) use ($ticket) {

        /* New test more complicated which cannot be
           tested with a rule */
        if ($this_test_is_complex_and_fails) {
            $validator->errors()->add('validateTicket', 'This is another problem');
            return false;
        }
    });
    return $validator;
}
```