# Laravel 5.5 validation minimum length only when field is required

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have the following validation rule:

```
'lightboard_line_1' => 'required_without_all:lightboard_line_2,lightboard_line_3|min:1|max:10',
'lightboard_line_2' => 'required_without_all:lightboard_line_1,lightboard_line_3|min:1|max:10',
'lightboard_line_3' => 'required_without_all:lightboard_line_1,lightboard_line_2|min:1|max:10',
```

So the idea is that when `lightboard_line_2` has a value, `lightboard_line_1` and `lightboard_line_3` are no longer required.
Because of the `min` and `max` rule, they do require a value at the moment.

Is there a way in which I can assure a minimum value ONLY when the field has a value and is required?

The HTML code for the fields:

```
<input name="lightboard_line_1" type="text">
<input name="lightboard_line_2" type="text">
<input name="lightboard_line_3" type="text">
```

Comment: Then you are using the wrong validation rule...you should be using required_if: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777265/required-if-laravel-5-validation

Comment: @lewis4u Can you explain why? There should be at least one field with a value. So If `lightboard_line_1` has a value, `lightboard_line_2` and `lightboard_line_3` are allowed to be empty. When `lightboard_line_3` has a value, `lightboard_line_1` and `lightboard_line_2` are allowed to be empty. As I understand `required_if`, this will require all fields to have a value when one field has a value?

Comment: First let me know what kind of input type are your fields? text, select-box or something else?

Comment: @lewis4u I've updated my question with the HTML code. It's all text.

Comment: Define "assure a minimum value" what exactly do you mean? Your rules now are assuring that the value must be between 1 and 10. And what do you want?

Comment: All fields now need to have at least one character as a value, even when they are not required. When I have a value for `lightboard_line_1`, `lightboard_line_2` and `lightboard_line_3` still need a value because of the `min` and `max` rules. I want the `min` and `max` rules applied only when the field is required.

Comment: I see now what the problem is. That minimum maximum wants to have some value. And that is triggering the rule to fail even if you use required_without_all

Comment: But anyway why do you have 3 text fields for that. Are there 3 different models on which you are applying this in your app or what?

Comment: What if lightboard_line_1 is 1.000.000 but lightboard_line_2 is 5. Should it fail because lightboard_line_1 execeeds the limit, or just ignore it because there is a lightboard_line_2 that is correct?

Comment: @lewis4u, the value of these input fields are generated on some image, they need to be on different positions. That's why I have 3 fields. So there's only on model that uses these input fields.

Comment: @Amarnasan Than `lightboard_line_1` should fail but `lightboard_line_2` should pass.

Comment: I think you want to include one "numeric" rule to all of them... otherwise those min and max will be calculated upon the size of the string rather than the value.

Comment: @Amarnasan they are text fields, I don't want to force a numeric input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution, I'm now validating using this code:

```
        /** @var Validator $validator */
        $validator = \Validator::make( $request->request->all(), [
            'lightboard_line_1' => 'required_without_all:lightboard_line_2,lightboard_line_3',
            'lightboard_line_2' => 'required_without_all:lightboard_line_1,lightboard_line_3',
            'lightboard_line_3' => 'required_without_all:lightboard_line_1,lightboard_line_2'
        ], [
            'required_without_all' => __( 'At least line is required' ),
            'min'                  => __( 'Your input should be at least :min characters' ),
            'max'                  => __( 'Your input cannot be more than :max characters' )
        ] );

        $validator->sometimes(
            'lightboard_line_1',
            'required|min:5|max:10',
            function ( $input ) {
                return ! empty( $input->lightboard_line_1 );
            }
        );
        $validator->sometimes(
            'lightboard_line_2',
            'required|min:5|max:10',
            function ( $input ) {
                return ! empty( $input->lightboard_line_2 );
            }
        );
        $validator->sometimes(
            'lightboard_line_3',
            'required|min:5|max:10',
            function ( $input ) {
                return ! empty( $input->lightboard_line_3 );
            }
        );
```

Comment: Wow... what a convoluted elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would update the validation rules to:

```
$rules = [
  'lightboard_line_1' => 'required_without_all:lightboard_line_2,lightboard_line_3',
  'lightboard_line_2' => 'required_without_all:lightboard_line_1,lightboard_line_3',
  'lightboard_line_3' => 'required_without_all:lightboard_line_1,lightboard_line_2',
];
```

Then, before checking the rules against the rules, I would dynamically modify the rules based on which input was completed, e.g.:

```
if ( $request->has('lightboard_line_1') ) {
  // append to the rule
  $rules['lightboard_line_1'] .= '|min:1|max:10';
} else if ( ...
```

This way, the `min` and `max` are only enforced for the field that has been completed. Feel free to optimise the code as required.