# How to handle this validation context?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this registration form below.

```
// registration form in the registration page


 <form method="post" id="step1form" action="">
      {{csrf_field()}}
        <p>Is not necessary additional info.
       Your tickets will be sent to the email
     <b>
    {{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}</b>.</p>

      @if (!empty($allParticipants))
        @if($allParticipants == 1)
            @foreach($selectedTypes as $selectedType)
                @foreach(range(1,$selectedType['quantity']) as $test)
                  <p>Please enter  the following 
                  information for each participant</p>
                  <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                    <label for="name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="name"
                           name="name" value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->name : old('name')}}">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                    <label for="surname" class="text-gray">Surname</label>
                    <input type="text" id="surname" required class="form-control" name="surname" value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->surname : old('surname')}}">
                  </div>

                <h6>Participant - 1 - {{$test}}</h6>

              <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                <label for="participant_name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="participant_name[]" required class="form-control" value="">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                <label for="participant_surname" class="text-gray">Surname</label>
                <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="participant_surname[]" value="">
              </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="ttypes[]" value="{{ $selectedType['id'] }}"/>
              @foreach($selectedType['questions'] as $customQuestion)
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
                <input type="text"
                       @if($customQuestion->pivot->required == "1") required @endif
                class="form-control" name="participant_question[]">
                <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]"
                       value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}" name="participant_question_id[]"/>
              </div>
              @endforeach
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
        @endif
      @endif
      <input type="submit" href="#step2" id="goToStep2" value="Go to step 2"/>
    </form>
```

If "all_participants" column is "1" in the congress table, the user needs to introduce some registration info, to introduce the info(name and surname) of each participant.

If the all_participants column is "0", it appears the "`<p>Is not necessary additional info.</p>`" and the user dont need to introduce any information to register in the congress because its used his authentication information to do the registration in the congress.

But when the all_participants column is "0" there is a issue. Because in the RegistrationController in the method that handles the registration I have some rules:

```
 $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'surname' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'email' => 'required|max:255|email',
            'participant_name.*' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'participant_surname.*' => 'required|max:255|string',
        ];
```

**Issue:** So when the  all_participants column is "0" and the user click in "go to step 2" it appears some validation errors. Do you know how to correct the issue?

full method that handles the registration:

```
public function storeRegistration(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){

        $user = Auth::user();

        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'surname' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'email' => 'required|max:255|email',
            'participant_name.*' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'participant_surname.*' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'participant_email.*' => 'required|max:255|email',
        ];

        $messages = [
            'participant_question.*.required' => 'The participant is required'
        ];

        if($request->participant_question_required){
            foreach ($request->participant_question_required as $key => $value) {
                $rule = 'string|max:255'; 
                // if this was required, ie 1, prepend "required|" to the rule
                if ($value) {
                    $rule = 'required|' . $rule;
                }

                // individual rule for this array key to the $rules array
                $rules["participant_question.{$key}"] = $rule;
            }
        }

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

        if($validator->passes())
        {
            $registration = Registration::create([
                'congress_id' => $id,
                'main_user_id' => $user->id,
                'status' => 'C',
            ]);
                if($request->participant_name) {

                    $participants = [];

                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_name); $i++)
                        $participants[] = Participant::create([
                            'name' => $request->participant_name[$i],
                            'surname' => $request->participant_surname[$i],
                            'email' => $request->participant_email[$i],
                            'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                            'ticket_type_id' => $request->ttypes[$i]
                        ]);
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_question); $i++)
                        $answer = Answer::create([
                            'question_id' => $request->participant_question_id[$i],
                            'participant_id' => $participants[$i]->id,
                            'answer' => $request->participant_question[$i],
                        ]);
                }
                else{
                    $participant = Participant::create([
                        'name' => $request->name,
                        'surname' => $request->surname,
                        'email' => $request->email,
                        'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                        'ticket_type_id' => '1'
                    ]);
                }
    }
```

// storeRegistrationInfo() is like that now:

```
public function storeRegistrationInfoF(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){

        $allParticipants = Congress::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;

        if($allParticipants){
            $user = Auth::user();

            $rules = [
                'name' => 'required_unless:all_participants,0|max:255|string',
                'surname' => 'required_unless:all_participants,0|max:255|string',
                'email' => 'required_unless:all_participants,0|max:255|email',
                'participant_name.*' => 'required_unless:all_participants,0|max:255|string',
                'participant_surname.*' => 'required_unless:all_participants,0|max:255|string',
                'participant_email.*' => 'required_unless:all_participants,0|max:255|email',
            ];

            $messages = [
                'participant_question.*.required' => 'The participant is required'
            ];


            if($request->participant_question_required){
                foreach ($request->participant_question_required as $key => $value) {
                    $rule = 'string|max:255'; 

                    // if this was required, ie 1, prepend "required|" to the rule
                    if ($value) {
                        $rule = 'required|' . $rule;
                    }
                    $rules["participant_question.{$key}"] = $rule;
                }
            }

            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

            if($validator->passes()) {

                $registration = Registration::create([
                    'congress_id' => $id,
                    'main_user_id' => $user->id,
                    'status' => 'C',

                ]);

                if ($request->participant_name) {

                    $participants = [];

                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_name); $i++)
                        $participants[] = Participant::create([
                            'name' => $request->participant_name[$i],
                            'surname' => $request->participant_surname[$i],
                            'email' => $request->participant_email[$i],
                            'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                            'ticket_type_id' => $request->ttypes[$i]

                        ]);
                }
            }

            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'success'
            ], 200);
        }
        else {
            $user = Auth::user();

            $registration = Registration::create([
                'congress_id' => $id,
                'main_user_id' => $user->id,
                'status' => 'C',

            ]);
            $participant = Participant::create([
                'name' => $user->name,
                'surname' => $user->surname,
                'email' => $user->email,
                'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                'ticket_type_id' => '1' // test
            ]);
        }
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        $errors =  json_decode($errors);

        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'errors' => $errors
        ], 422);
    }
```

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? Btw, if you include `php` tag in your question the code will be automatically highlighted! I edited it now, but it's a nice thing to know

Comment: Instead of having required for participant fields, replace it with `nullable` if those fields are not mandatory. Otherwise, check this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777265/required-if-laravel-5-validation

Comment: Thanks, the validation errors is that the name, surname and email are required fields.

Comment: For the participant_name and participant_surname dont appears any validation error.

Comment: errors
:
{name: ["The name field is required."], surname: ["The surname field is required."],…}
email
:
["The email field is required."]
name
:
["The name field is required."]
surname
:
["The surname field is required."]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your validation will always require you to have values whether your `$allParticipants` is `> 0` or not you need to make sure if that `allParticipants` is greater than `0` to allow validation otherwise skip it.

```
public function storeRegistration(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){
  // get your `$allParticipants` here
  if($allParticipants) {
    // put your logic here
  } else{
    // get the auth user
    // and register him if there is no particpants
    $user = Auth::user();
    $registration = Registration::create([
          'congress_id' => $id,
          'main_user_id' => $user->id,
          'status' => 'C',
    ]);
  }
});
```

here's how your function need to look like:

public function storeRegistrationInfoF(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){

```
    $allParticipants = Congress::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;

    if($allParticipants){
        $user = Auth::user();

        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required_unless:all_participants,0|max:255|string',
            'surname' => 'required_unless:all_participants,0|max:255|string',
            'email' => 'required_unless:all_participants,0|max:255|email',
            'participant_name.*' => 'required_unless:all_participants,0|max:255|string',
            'participant_surname.*' => 'required_unless:all_participants,0|max:255|string',
            'participant_email.*' => 'required_unless:all_participants,0|max:255|email',
        ];

        $messages = [
            'participant_question.*.required' => 'The participant is required'
        ];


        if($request->participant_question_required){
            foreach ($request->participant_question_required as $key => $value) {
                $rule = 'string|max:255'; 

                // if this was required, ie 1, prepend "required|" to the rule
                if ($value) {
                    $rule = 'required|' . $rule;
                }
                $rules["participant_question.{$key}"] = $rule;
            }
        }

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

        if($validator->passes()) {

            $registration = Registration::create([
                'congress_id' => $id,
                'main_user_id' => $user->id,
                'status' => 'C',

            ]);

            if ($request->participant_name) {

                $participants = [];

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_name); $i++)
                    $participants[] = Participant::create([
                        'name' => $request->participant_name[$i],
                        'surname' => $request->participant_surname[$i],
                        'email' => $request->participant_email[$i],
                        'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                        'ticket_type_id' => $request->ttypes[$i]

                    ]);
            }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'success'
        ], 200);
      }
     if($validator->fails()) {
       $errors = $validator->errors();

       return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'errors' => $errors
       ], 422);
      }
    }
    else {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $registration = Registration::create([
            'congress_id' => $id,
            'main_user_id' => $user->id,
            'status' => 'C',

        ]);
        $participant = Participant::create([
            'name' => $user->name,
            'surname' => $user->surname,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'registration_id' => $registration->id,
            'ticket_type_id' => '1' // test
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the validation even if all_participants is 0 should exist to verify if the name, surname and email are equal to the name, surname and email of the authenticated user right?

Comment: To get the column value is like that  "$allParticipants = Congress::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;". Then the code to put in if($allParticipants) {...} is what? Is all the code unless the rules "$rules = [
            'name' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'surname' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'email' => 'required|max:255|email',
            'participant_name.*' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'participant_surname.*' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'participant_email.*' => 'required|max:255|email',
        ];"?

Comment: But like that how is possible to do registrations when the allParticipants is 0?

Comment: This is what you did in your registration form right? you only have fields in your form if  `$allParticipants` is not empty.

Comment: But if "all_participants" is 0 the difference is that the user dont need to introduce information for each participant, the only necessary information is the info (name, surname and email) of the authenticated user, that is the user that is doing the registration

Comment: so in both cases the user info is required?

Comment: So is not necessary for the user introduce this information. But is necessary to also register the user if all_participants is "0", the only difference is that he dont need to introduce any information, it appears  only the message " <p>Is not necessary additional info.Your tickets will be sent to {{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}"instead of the registration form.

Comment: Yes is required, the only difference is that if all_participant is "1" means that the user needs to introduce for each paricipant (for each selcted ticket) the name and surname. If all_participant is "0" is not necessary collect info of all participants and so is just necessary to use the info of the authenticted user to do the registration.

Comment: Thanks, I update the quesiton with the code as it is but it appears "{message: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::errors()",…}". Do you know why?

Comment: check my answer please.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if is possible to instead of have two "        $user = Auth::user();" have just one? And also if is better to have this "    $allParticipants = Congress::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;" or instead have a input hidden in the registration form with the value of $allParticipants and then instead of  "$allParticipants = Congress::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;"  have only $request->all_participants?

Comment: And also do you know if is necessary to have some rules to validate if the info of the authenticated user "$user->name, $user->email and $user->email" obtained from " $user = Auth::user();
" is valid? That is that is equal to the info in the db?

Comment: Not it's better of keep it as it's since the hidden field could by changed by the user. and of course it's valid to get the data form `Auth::user();` it's just facade. And you can extract all the repeated logic into a private helpers.

Comment: Thanks, but is  necessary to have " $user = Auth::user();" twice?