# required if in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, required

I'm using required if in Laravel validation, but it doesnt work. what is my mistake?

```
public function rules()
{
    if (!empty($this->game_id)) {
                $game = Game::find($this->game_id);
                $game_type = $game->type;
            } else {
                $game_type = 'sport';
            }

   return [
                'game_id' => 'required',
                'platform_id' => 'required_if:' . $game_type . ',==,electronic',
          ]
}
```

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777265/required-if-laravel-5-validation

Comment: your field name `game_type` seems to be dynamic, make sure it's an valid input name

Comment: yes, its value is sport or electronic. I would like to required it when `game_type` is equals to `electronic`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the whole expression, the correct format is as follows:

```
 return [
                'game_id' => 'required',
                'platform_id' => 'required_if:columnName:value',
          ];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The columnName is from another table. how can I call it in this columnName?

Comment: You might need to write your own validator rule for that.

Comment: `required_if` docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-if

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
public function rules()
{
    if (!empty($this->game_id)) {
                $game = Game::find($this->game_id);
                $game_type = $game->type;
            } else {
                $game_type = 'sport';
            }

   return [
                'game_id' => 'required',
                'platform_id' => 'required_if: . $game_type . ,==,electronic',
          ]
}
```

The syntax for `required_if` is `'field_name' => 'required_if:columnName:value'`. What you're doing is wrapping the `columnName` in `''` single quotes!

Comment: Thanks for your response. The columnName is from another table. how can I call it in this columnName?

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: User create a tournament. When he/she select a `game_id`, I will check its `type` as `game_type` from game table. The `platform_id` in tournament table is required if the `game_type` of that `game_id` is equal to `electronic`.

Comment: @ShokouhDareshiri did you tried my code? I got what you're trying to do but this code will work give a try and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in my own rules as below:

```
if (!empty($this->game_id)) {

      $game = Game::find($this->game_id);
      $game_type = $game->type;

          if($game_type == 'electronic'){
                  $required = 'required';
                } else{
                    $required = ' ';
                }

          }

return [
         'game_id' => 'required',
         'platform_id' => $required,
       ]
```

Comment: Good to know :)