# How to require a field if a particular checkbox is checked in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel, I have three checkboxes: WhatsApp, Email and SMS

What I want to accomplish in my validation CustomerRequest, is to require the Email field if the Checkbox for email is checked:

Below is a sample of my rules:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'choix' => 'required',
            'tel' => 'required|max:25',
            'contract' => 'required|numeric|max:9',
            'nom' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|max:50',
            'language' => 'required|max:2',
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
            'conditionAccepted' => 'accepted',
        ];
    }
```

Below is my checkbox field:

```
 <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 " style="text-align : left; margin-left:20px;" ><label class="checkbox-inline check"> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="choix[]" value="WHA">
                            <span style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px; position: absolute;">WhatsApp</span></label></div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 " style="text-align : left; margin-left:20px;" ><label class="checkbox-inline check"> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="choix[]" value="SMS">
                            <span style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px; position: absolute;">SMS</span></label></div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 " style="text-align : left; margin-left:20px;" ><label class="checkbox-inline check"> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="choix[]" value="MAIL">
                            <span style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px; position: absolute;">Email</span></label></div>

                </div>
```

Appreciate guidance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [required\_if Laravel 5 validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777265/required-if-laravel-5-validation)

Comment: Hi @Don'tPanic, I have tried `'email' => 'required_if:choix,==,MAIL|max:50',`, but it doesn't work. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `required_with` validation rule. Check the whole list in the docs, there are many helpful validation rules https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-required-unless

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue with the following code:

```
'choix.*' => 'in:WHA,SMS,MAIL',
'tel' => 'required|max:25',
'contract' => 'required|digits:9|exists:accounts,sic_code',
'nom' => 'required|max:255',
'email' => 'required_if:choix.MAIL,==,MAIL|nullable|email|max:50',
'language' => 'required|max:2',
'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
'conditionAccepted' => 'accepted',
```