# Laravel, how to execute a rule only if the previous one is true

Tags: laravel, validation

How can i execute the rule only if the previous one is true?
For example:

```
$input = request()->get('data');
$rules = [
   "id_country" => "required",
   "fiscalcode" => "required_if:id_country,128|fiscalcode",
]
$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

Now the problem is that the 'fiscalcode' rule is always verified, instead i want it to be verified only if the previous rule (required_if:id_country,128) is true.
How can i do this in a single check?

Comment: Use it as `"fiscalcode" => "required_if:id_country,==,128"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [required\_if Laravel 5 validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777265/required-if-laravel-5-validation)

Comment: You can add [bail](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#stopping-on-first-validation-failure) to your rule so that it will stop on the first failure.

Comment: I tried with "required_if:id_country,==,128" and with "bail" but the result does not change.

Comment: It should be `'bail|required_if:id_country,128|fiscalcode`. You don't need the comparison because [required_if already checks to see if id_country is a certain value](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-required-if)

Comment: "bail" not work with "required_if"! In the post data I have `"id_country" => "4" , "fiscalcode" => "123456"` the "fiscalcode" rule must not apply, instead i get the invalid fiscal code error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this...

```
"fiscalcode" => ["required_if:id_country,128",Rule::when((int)$input['id_country'] == 128,"fiscalcode")],
```